# How many ways to form two teams of five out of 11 players?

Tags: combinatorics

From my understanding, this would be 11!/(5!*5!*2!). However, I saw a different solution where it stated that the solution would be 11C5 X 6C5, meaning that we first choose the five and then from the remaining six we choose 5 again for the total number of combinations. These two solutions yield different answers but it seems like both make sense logically to me. Which one is right?

Comment: One is twice the other. The $2$ comes from do you care which team is which? Perhaps you are gonna give them a different Jersey to each time. What if both Jerseys are different? What if they are equal? Those are your two solutions. So it depends of what do you mean by "form".

Comment: @Phicar By form I just mean players are selected from the 11 people. I do not care which team is which.

Comment: So, the first one is right. In the second one you are choosing first for the first team and next to the second. This gives them a difference.

Comment: @Phicar Thanks, but now I'm thinking wouldn't it be 11!/(5!*5!*3!) instead? (changed the 2! to a 3!) Since there are actually 3 groups if I include the isolated 1 person that is not part of the 2 groups of 5?

Comment: @diagoot - no, as the third team is easy to distinguish, having fewer members

Comment: @Henry What do you mean by easy to distinguish? I was thinking we need to get rid of the order counted in the 3 permutated groups since I think it would also count when it's 1 5 5 or 5 5 1 or 5 1 5 when these are really just the same

Comment: @diagoot The division by $2!$ is not really a question of order but one of being unable to distinguish between teams of equal size